# Claim auth from ADFS

Tags: development, active-directory, authentication, sharepoint-online, adfs

I asked this question @StackOverflow[1] but maybe this is a better location for it:

I try to connect to a SharePoint Online instance via a WPF-Application (C#). I have found this article[2] that discribes a possible solution but the problem is that the specific instance has a Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) infront and I don't know how to get the auth-token. (I can't create a certificate for my application to authentificate against the adfs.)

Anyone who have already done this and can support me with some code snippets?

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295953/claim-auth-from-adfs

[2] http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Working against a claims based SharePoint site unfortunately isn't simple. The best resource is probably the blog [Share-n-dipity](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka) the article [Using the Client Object Model with a Claims Based Auth Site in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/06/04/using-the-client-object-model-with-a-claims-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) has code for a Windows Forms app which might be a good starting point.